# What javascript-only KoTH challenges have there been?

Tags: discussion, king-of-the-hill

### Alternative title: Look! I made a thing!

The recent [Formic Functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135102/8927) challenge was a lot of fun, and seems to have taken the concept of easy-to-run online javascript-based king-of-the-hill challenges to a new level. It's inspired me to make a framework for building them, which I invite people to take a look at!

https://github.com/davidje13/koth-webplayer

(I have a vague idea for a KoTH challenge of my own, which I plan to build with this framework)

For those saying "wait, haven't we seen [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10572/8927) [before](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/introducing-a-koth-server)?": I for one think that the ease of just visiting a website and typing in some code gives this new style a much lower bar-to-entry for competitors, and the ability to develop games without any setup whatsoever (you can literally download the code and open the html files) gives a much lower bar-to-entry for contest writers.

---

### My Question

I've been cloning past challenges to drive out the functionality, but so far I've only found 3:

- https://davidje13.github.io/koth-webplayer/formic.htm — [Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135102/8927)
- https://davidje13.github.io/koth-webplayer/battlebots.htm —
  [Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48353/8927)
- https://davidje13.github.io/koth-webplayer/botflocks.htm —
  [Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50690/8927)

There must be others out there. Does anybody remember any?

Comment: Personally, I don't think this is really on-topic for meta, but I won't VTC just yet. If you ask in chat, however, I'm sure people will be willing to help out.

Comment: Wow, Your Formic Functions one runs so fast.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I had the same concern, but there are some not-too-old questions here in the same vein, so I thought I'd risk it. Also I wanted this to be a bit of a collection of javascript-based challenges, which I think meta can do better than chat.

Comment: @H.PWiz Web Workers, yo!

Comment: Wow web workers really make a difference - runs fast even on mobile. I have lots to learn...

Comment: I wish the formic one was a screensaver :)

Comment: @FrenzyLi sounds fair. https://davidje13.github.io/koth-webplayer/formic.htm#screensaver (use with your choice of website-as-screensaver program). Wouldn't recommend leaving it on for too long though; probably not good for your electricity bill!

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67560/king-of-the-hill-spacewar is a javascript based KoTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are all the questions tagged king-of-the-hill and javascript:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill+javascript

Comment: Wha? huh. When I tried doing that I just got a bunch of answers for KoTH challenges which *happened* to be written in Javascript. This looks much better! I'll slip away in shame now… (thanks; I'll get cloning!)

Comment: @Dave The difference is that that request searches only questions. You can get similar functionality from the search box by using `is:q`.

Comment: You can also search specifically for tags by enclosing the tag name in square brackets. For example `[king-of-the-hill] [javascript]`